# Windows Phone emulator is not running

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I've installed **Visual Studio 2012** on my laptop, then I installed **Windows Phone SDK 8.0**. Then I made a test project. But when I click **Emulator WVGA 512MB**   a pop-up window came up and it showed the following error message :

```
 Can't start the Windows Phone Emulator

 The Windows Phone Emulator couldn't start because 
 the hypervisor isn't running. The likely cause is that
 hardware-assisted virtualization isn't turned on.

 Check you PC's BIOS and make sure that hardware-
 assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data
 execution protection are turned on.
 More information
```

Then an error is shown, which is `0x80131500`, My **SLAT** in **BIOS** is enable and My PC configuration is

```
 Windows 8 Pro

 Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz 2.27GHz
 Installed memory (RAM):  3.00 GB (2.86 GB usable)
 System type:    64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
 Pen and Touch: No Pen or Touch Input is available for this Display
```

**my Virtualization of BIOS is also enabled**

Comment: did you check your visual studio updates

Comment: Yes, I update my Visual Studio and still no result

Comment: need to update your computer configuration

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue,it was because i haven't enabled the **Hyper-V platform** in the windows features tab, to enable the goto startscreen and type `optionalfeatures` click on Hyper-V ,check on **Hyper-V Management Tools and Hyper-V Platform** if you already have them enabled try to remove and re-enable them.

Comment: I have also checked my Hyper-V and it is enabled. I think my problem is  in my computer configuration, I install windows phone SDK 8.0 on different computer and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

```
To turn Hyper-V back on, use:
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on
or
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
and reboot.
```

Also see this for more information

http://www.ivobeerens.nl/2013/12/16/running-hyper-v-and-vmware-workstation-on-windows-8-x/
http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/running-hyper-v-and-virtualbox-on-the-same-computer/